# Problem using ContactsContract.Data when query

Tags: android

I am learning android developing. Well, my appwidget failed at this line:

```
Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI,
                new String[] {Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME},
                Contacts.STARRED + "=0", null, null);
```

May I know why? Thanks.

Added: I have tried a few ways I used in Java to debug this line, all I got was "stop unexpectedly".

Comment: Post more info about 'failed' what exception is fired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example that retrieves all data based on name.  I notice a couple of differences, so maybe you can compare and figure out your problem:

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, "DISPLAY_NAME = '" + NAME + "'", null, null);